# Issues installing tensorflow in anaconda

Tags: python, installation, tensorflow, anaconda

I've been using the anaconda installation on [their site](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation). It seems to work and I'm able to create the tensor flow environment. After this, I seem to encounter some issues. I move from my terminal to my Ipynb and try `import tensorflow as tf` and I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I did some googling and found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3217) which says I may be running the script in the same directory as tensorflow. This seems simple but I don't know how to go about doing this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is displayed if you install the GPU-enabled Mac OS version of TensorFlow on a machine that does not have CUDA installed.

To fix this, you can try doing either of the following.

## Remove the conda package, and install the CPU only version.

```
# Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 2.7:
conda remove tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=0.10.0
```

You can see the package here - https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow

## Use Pip instead of Anaconda

Make a new environment or remove the package from conda and try the following:

```
# Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 2.7:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl
$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried that and I got the following error: `Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.` I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Sorry about that! Could you try this: `pip install protobuf --upgrade`

Comment: and now i'm getting this error: `ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow`

Comment: You're running the script in the same directory as tensorflow. Move it out and you should be fine.

Comment: i'm not quite sure how to do that. This is the current directory for tensorflow: /Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/envs/tensorflow

Comment: Make a new file 'test.py' with your import statement, save it in a folder, and run that script from that folder as `python test.py` from inside that folder.

Comment: would a ipynb work as well? so i opened a new ipynb called test and trying to import tensorflow and im getting the same error as my first comment.

Comment: Are you on a mac or Windows? So I can give you complete instructions.

Comment: this is odd, i did what you suggested and created a random file in my Documents folder with my import statement and it ran without errors. I tried to do the same in my ipynb and it gives me the same errors

Comment: I'm on a mac, OS X El Capitan

Comment: Great! Now, start your ipython notebook from another (say your Documents) folder.

Comment: You could open a new terminal window and start your notebook from there as well, any  folder except the tensorflow folder.

Comment: so when i do this it initially says it can't find the tensorflow module but i usually use `import sys` `sys.path.append('/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages')` and that finds the module but when i do that, i get the same errors

Comment: Okay, it's not good practice to do that. You should, add a kernel to your notebook. You can do this going into the terminal (from where you ran the previous code and it worked) follow the same process to reach that and then type `ipython kernel install`. Now you can choose the new kernel you just added in your notebook.

Comment: Ok, so it installed on the random ipynb which is great! but when I get rid of that code, It's no longer able to find a bunch of the packages that I imported. Should I create a kernel in that `site-packages` folder?

Comment: Also, when I run that command, a new kernel isn't showing up in my ipynb

Comment: That's great! If I helped you in any way, do upvote and mark as answer. Thanks!